# jQuery .on keyup firing when no key press

Tags: jquery

I am using `$(function() {});` to run jQuery events on page load.

I have a data filtering form that uses 3 input elements to filter data by keywords (year, make, model). All three have the same class, to which I assign an `.on("keyup")` handler which submits the (one or two or three) values entered to a PHP script, which returns json.

Problem: after typing input, the results are filtered as expected, however a moment later, the results are loaded again, but this time as if the page had just loaded (all results).

Here is some of the code:

```
function load_vehicle_fitment(args) {
if(args === undefined) {
    args = {};
}

args['func'] = 'print_fitment';

$.get('ajax_get.php', args,
    function(data) {
        $('#fitment_data').html(data.html);
}, "json");
}


$(function() {
// INITIAL
load_vehicle_fitment();

// FILTER YMM COMBOS
$(".filter_input").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var typed_length = $(this).val().length;

    if(typed_length < 1 || typed_length > 2) {
        var args = {};
        var year = $("#year").val();
        var make = $("#make").val();
        var model = $("#model").val();

        if(year.length > 3) {
            args["year"] = year;
        }
        if(make.length > 2) {
            args["make"] = make;
        }
        if(model.length > 2) {
            args["model"] = model;
        }

        load_vehicle_fitment(args);
    }
});

});
```

What is causing this behavior??

---

UPDATE:

The search form:

```
<form name="vehicle_search" method="get" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="vehicles">
<input type="text" id="year" name="year" maxlength="4" size="2" class="filter_input" placeholder="Year" value="" style="padding: 3px;" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="make" name="make" class="filter_input" placeholder="Make" value="" style="padding: 3px;">
<input type="text" id="model" name="model" class="filter_input" placeholder="Model" value="" style="padding: 3px;">
<input type="submit" value="Add" id="add_vehicle_button" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

---

UPDATE:

@Kevin B, @teewuane
I have wrapped the jQuery request in a setTimeout, which basically makes it so that it "waits" until it has been n miliseconds after a keyup, at which point it runs. This saves http requests from this happening:

```
XHR finished loading: ".../ajax_get.php?year=1982&make=F". 
XHR finished loading: ".../ajax_get.php?year=1982&make=Fo". 
XHR finished loading: ".../ajax_get.php?year=1982&make=For". 
XHR finished loading: ".../ajax_get.php?year=1982&make=Ford".
```

The funny thing is, this seems to have corrected the error I was experiencing. It hurts that I don't know exactly why.

Comment: You're making an ajax call after every keyup, which will cause you mamy many problems going forward. I'd recommend loading the data up front and filtering on data locally.

Also, since you are not using deferreds, it's possibly you're encountering race conditions with your ajax calls.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as abandoning on-keyup lookups, however you should atleast throttle it and abort existing lookups when a new one is started.

Comment: What type of input is .filter_input? Do you have any attributes like "autofocus" on the element?

Comment: @teewuane I have added the search form html.

Comment: @systemizer How do I use "deferreds"? How would I accomplish filtering locally? Loading data into a json object, then... how do I filter the json object?

Comment: @AVProgrammer what version of jquery are you using? If it is older than 1.7 I think what you are doing will not work properly. You'd need to use $(".filter_input").bind('keyup', ........

Comment: @AVProgrammer I think you need to track when a look up is in progress so that you can determine that you want to abort it or wait for it. It is very hard to see exactly what is happening without having a live demo that is producing what you are getting. But I would guess that it sent off several requests (1 for each 'keyup') and one is just getting back 'a moment later' that had an undefined value for 'args' so it empties args{}; .. Either way, live demo or it didn't happen ;)

Comment: @teewuane There is too much going on here to replicate on jfiddle; and I cannot link to the live version. But I do understand your point :) See my latest update ^

Comment: @KevinB Please post comment as an answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't go as far as abandoning on-keyup lookups, however you should at least throttle it and abort existing lookups when a new one is started.